TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method recordlinkage.Index
Could you please help to solve the issue with error regarding indices?
df18 =pd.DataFrame({'Index': [0,1,2,3,4,],
    'Name': ['Anna', 'Jan', 'Pawel','Sonia', "Klaudia"],
    'Age': [20,25,30,35,35],
    'Birthday': ['2004-01-01','1999-01-01','1994-01-01','1989-01-01','1999-01-01',]
} )
df19 =pd.DataFrame({'Index': [0,1,2,3,4,],
    'Name': ['Anna', 'Gabi', 'Diwa','Emil', "Klaudia"],
    'Age': [20,30,30,35,35],
    'Birthday': ['2004-01-01','1994-01-01','1994-01-01','1989-01-01','1999-01-01',]
})

df18["Index"] = df18["Index"].astype('int')
df19["Index"] = df19["Index"].astype('int')

df18 = df18.set_index('Index')
df19 = df19.set_index('Index')

import recordlinkage

indexer = recordlinkage.Index('')
indexer.block('Age')
pairs = indexer.index(df18,df19)

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an index method
I tried to set the index and change the type into int, but nothing help.

You can do it this way:
import pandas as pd
import recordlinkage

df18 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Name': ['Anna', 'Jan', 'Pawel', 'Sonia', 'Klaudia'],
    'Age': [20, 25, 30, 35, 35],
    'Birthday': ['2004-01-01', '1999-01-01', '1994-01-01', '1989-01-01', '1999-01-01']
})

df19 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Name': ['Anna', 'Gabi', 'Diwa', 'Emil', 'Klaudia'],
    'Age': [20, 30, 30, 35, 35],
    'Birthday': ['2004-01-01', '1994-01-01', '1994-01-01', '1989-01-01', '1999-01-01']
})

df18.set_index('Index', inplace=True)
df19.set_index('Index', inplace=True)

indexer = recordlinkage.Index()
indexer.block('Age')

pairs = indexer.index(df18, df19)

print(pairs)

which gives you
MultiIndex([(0, 0),
            (2, 1),
            (2, 2),
            (3, 3),
            (3, 4),
            (4, 3),
            (4, 4)],
           names=['Index_1', 'Index_2'])

